# Svg animation unexpectedly stop in a few minutes

Tags: html, svg, svg-animate

First of all, please look into below snippet, you will see the repeated animations which five balls move along one path.

But unfortunately, you will find the first ball will stop at `m0,0` in a few minutes, later, the following balls stop one by one.

Even I ajdusted `dur="0.4s"` to `dur="0.39s"`, it still had same issue. (I thought it was caused by the bound value of `dur`).

**Updated:**

I found the SVG seemed working fine (at least ran 5 hours) in Firefox (latest version).

Google Chrome (latest version) will have the above issue mentioned.

It seems Chrome can't support SVG animation very well.

**Updated 2:**

For Chrome, it seems only `<animateMotion>` has the issue, because I ran [this SVG](https://jsfiddle.net/johnnnnn/wrchnoum/2/) with only `<animate>`, there is not any issue so far (at least two hours).

Thanks.

```css
svg{
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
}
```

```html
<svg fill="#435063" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <g>
    <path d="m-40,0 q-8, -7, 0, -15 l40, 0 l0,15"
          stroke="#529fd9" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="route1"></path>
    <path d="m0,0 l-40, 0" stroke="#529fd9" stroke-width="1" fill="none" id="route2"></path>
    <ellipse cx="53" cy="32" rx="3" ry="3" stroke-width="1">
      <animateMotion id="a1" dur="1.6s" begin="0s;a1.end+0.4s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route2"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animateMotion dur="0.39s" begin="a1.end">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route1"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animate
             attributeName="ry"
             values="3;2;2;2;3"
             begin="a1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
      <animate
             attributeName="rx"
             values="3;5;5;5;3"
             begin="a1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse cx="53" cy="32" rx="3" ry="3" stroke-width="1">
      <animateMotion id="b1" dur="1.6s" begin="0.4s;b1.end+0.4s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route2"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animateMotion dur="0.39s" begin="b1.end">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route1"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animate
             attributeName="ry"
             values="3;2;2;2;3"
             begin="b1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
      <animate
             attributeName="rx"
             values="3;5;5;5;3"
             begin="b1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse cx="53" cy="32" rx="3" ry="3" stroke-width="1">
      <animateMotion id="c1" dur="1.6s" begin="0.8s;c1.end+0.4s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route2"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animateMotion dur="0.39s" begin="c1.end">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route1"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animate
             attributeName="ry"
             values="3;2;2;2;3"
             begin="c1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
      <animate
             attributeName="rx"
             values="3;5;5;5;3"
             begin="c1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse cx="53" cy="32" rx="3" ry="3" stroke-width="1">
      <animateMotion id="d1" dur="1.6s" begin="1.2s;d1.end+0.4s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route2"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animateMotion dur="0.39s" begin="d1.end">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route1"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animate
             attributeName="ry"
             values="3;2;2;2;3"
             begin="d1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
      <animate
             attributeName="rx"
             values="3;5;5;5;3"
             begin="d1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
    </ellipse>
    <ellipse cx="53" cy="32" rx="3" ry="3" stroke-width="1">
      <animateMotion id="e1" dur="1.6s" begin="1.6s;e1.end+0.4s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route2"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animateMotion dur="0.39s" begin="e1.end">
        <mpath xlink:href="#route1"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
      <animate
             attributeName="ry"
             values="3;2;2;2;3"
             begin="e1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
      <animate
             attributeName="rx"
             values="3;5;5;5;3"
             begin="e1.end+0.05s" dur="0.32s"
            />
    </ellipse>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Below screenshot show two of balls already stop.**
[image]

Comment: Could you specify in which environment you are experiencing described behavior? Perhaps there is nothing wrong with SVG itself, but some weird 'external' glitch kicks in… (Left the animation running in Chrome and Nightly and for few minutes and so far nothing broke.)

Comment: @myf, My broswer is Chrome. [SVG in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnnnnn/kz4abbax/106/), I designed the svg in JSFiddle, then just a few minutes later, it broke.

Comment: @myf, you are correct, I ran same svg in SO snippet and JSFiddler at the same time, but right now the animation of one ball in JSFiddle already stop, but working fine in SO snippet.

Comment: Yes, confirming, observed as well now in Chrome (both stable and Canary) at Win 10. Seems that some heavy CPU load and/or opening several linked JSFiddles might make glitch manifest itself sooner.

Comment: raise a [chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: Already raised, the link is [Issue 830009](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=830009#c4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was one bug for Chrome (**version <= M77**). Now it already been fixed since **>=M78** ([As the Chrome project member mentioned](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=830009#c10)).
So upgrade the chrome to latest version then works well.